# How to intercept requests using FeignClient

Tags: java, spring

I have an api #1, which redirects requests to another api #2, using RestController and FeingClient:

```
@RestController
@FeignClient(url = "${test-api-uri}", name = "test-v2", primary = false)
public interface TestApiController extends TestClient {
}
```

The test client is also FeignClient:

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "test-api-uri")
@FeignClient(url = "${test-api-uri}", name = "test-v1")
public interface TestClient extends ResourceClient
```

And ResourceClient:

```
public interface ResourceClient {

    @PostMapping ("/resources")
    ResourceDTO createResource(@RequestBody TestBody body,
                               @RequestHeader(USER_HEADER_NAME) String userName); 
}
```

So i want to intercept request when it hits api #1 with only TestBody request body, add header and then send to api #2